# React DatePicker get state from parent class

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, react-datepicker

In my form.js Im trying to get date selected from the date picker and update the state in form.js

Form.js

```
export default class form extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        Date: new Date(),
      };

      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }
    handleChange(event) {
      if(event.target.id === "delivery_date"){
        this.setState({Date: event.target.value});
     }

    render(){
   .....
    <CustomDatePicker id="delivery_date" value={this.state.selectedDate}   onChange={this.handleChange}></CustomDatePicker>
.....
    }
}
```

CustomDatePicker.js

```
export default function CustomDatePicker() {
    const [selectedDate, setDate] = useState(new Date());
    const isWeekday = date => {
      const day = getDay(date);
      return day !== 0 && day !== 6;
    };
    return (
        console.log({selectedDate}),
        <DatePicker 
          selected={selectedDate}
          onChange={date => setDate(date)}
          minDate={new Date()}
          maxDate={addDays(new Date(), 4)}
          // excludeDates={[new Date(), subDays(new Date(), 1)]} to exclude PB holiday
          filterDate={isWeekday}
          placeholderText="Select a date">
        </DatePicker>
    )
  }
}
```

I am able to print from console.log the selectedDaate from customDatePicker.js but i can't get the value in form.js

Comment: what do you mean you can't get the value in form.js? form is the one sending it to the picker

Comment: How do i get the selectedDate from CustomDatePicker.js in Form.js?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make CustomDatePicker call the onChange method on the props, and that way when the date changes, the Form.js method will be called

Have you tried this?

```
   <DatePicker 
      selected={selectedDate}
      onChange={date => {
         this.props.onChange(date)
         setDate(date)
      }
      minDate={new Date()}
      maxDate={addDays(new Date(), 4)}
      // excludeDates={[new Date(), subDays(new Date(), 1)]} to exclude PB holiday
      filterDate={isWeekday}
      placeholderText="Select a date">
    </DatePicker>
```

I can't test the code right now but this should give you an idea of what to do

Comment: I have an error this is undefined. I think its because i am using a function component from datepicker

Comment: You need to pass the props to the functional component: https://medium.com/@PhilipAndrews/react-how-to-access-props-in-a-functional-component-6bd4200b9e0b